# Set data field from getter and add extra computed field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I wanted to set fields inside data using getters:

```
export default {
 data () {
    return {
        medications: [],
       }
   },
  computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
        'allMedications',
        'getResidentsById',
    ]),
```

I wanted to set `medications = allMedications`, I know that we can user `{{allMedications}}` but my problem is suppose I have :

```
medications {
    name: '',
    resident: '', this contains id
    .......
   }
```

Now I wanted to call `getResidentsById` and set an extra field on **medications** as :

```
  medications {
    name: '',
    resident: '', this contains id
    residentName:'' add an extra computed field
    .......
   }
```

I have done this way :

```
watch: {
  allMedications() {
      // this.medications = this.allMedications
      const medicationArray = this.allMedications
      this.medications = medicationArray.map(medication => 
    ({
        ...medication,
        residentName: this.getResidentName(medication.resident)
    })
    );
    },
 },
 method: {
    getResidentName(id) {
      const resident = this.getResidentsById(id)
      return resident && resident.fullName
    },
  }
```

But this seems problem because only when there is change in the **allMedications** then method on **watch** gets active and **residentName** is set.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this you'll want the watcher to be run as soon as the component is created. You could move the logic within a method, and then call it from both the watcher and the created hook, but there is a simpler way.

You can use the [long-hand version](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) of the watcher in order to pass the `immediate: true` option. That will make it run instantly as soon as the computed property is resolved.

```
watch: {
  allMedications: {
    handler: function (val) {
      this.medications = val.map(medication => ({
        ...medication,
        residentName: this.getResidentName(medication.resident)
      });
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Also the allMedication in the watch is called twice on loading page. Is it because first time it is called during created and after that the allMedication in the getter is set and again the watch is called ?